# Why does id of child entity return 0 in response message in EclipseLink?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, one-to-one

I'm using a One-To-One association between my Member and MemberRoles tables. I wanted them to share the same id as PK and FK in the database and did it. But I've got another problem. When I insert a Member, a MemberRole record is being inserted with it and Member record has the correct id in return response but MemberRole id is incorrect. It returns 0 like this:

```
{
    "result": "Bulk user member saving is successfull. Members' informations are:",
    "memberList": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "firstName": "Michael",
            "lastName": "Schumacher",
            "email": "ilkay.gune2l@kod5.org",
            "enabled": false,
            "memberLanguageCode": "tr",
            "roleOfMember": {
                "id": 0,
                "email": "ilkay.gune2l@kod5.org",
                "role": "ROLE_USER"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My Member Entity Class:

```
package com.ilkaygunel.entities;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;

@Entity
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Member.findAll", query = "select m from Member m"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Member.findByFirstName", query = "select m from Member m where m.firstName =:firstName"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Member.findPasswordOfMember", query = "select m.password from Member m where m.id =:id"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Member.findByActivationToken", query = "select m from Member m where m.activationToken =:activationToken"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Member.findByEmail", query = "select m from Member m where m.email =:email") })
@Table(name = "MEMBER")
public class Member {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "MEMBER_ID")
    private long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private boolean enabled;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String memberLanguageCode;
    @Column(updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String activationToken;
    @Column(updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private LocalDateTime activationTokenExpDate;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "member", optional = false)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "MEMBER_ID")
    private MemberRoles roleOfMember;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Member [id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s', email='%s']", id, firstName, lastName,
                email);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        if (null != roleOfMember) {
            roleOfMember.setId(id);
        }
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public MemberRoles getRoleOfMember() {
        return roleOfMember;
    }

    public void setRoleOfMember(MemberRoles roleOfMember) {
        this.roleOfMember = roleOfMember;
    }

    public String getActivationToken() {
        return activationToken;
    }

    public void setActivationToken(String activationToken) {
        this.activationToken = activationToken;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getActivationTokenExpDate() {
        return activationTokenExpDate;
    }

    public void setActivationTokenExpDate(LocalDateTime activationTokenExpDate) {
        this.activationTokenExpDate = activationTokenExpDate;
    }

    public String getMemberLanguageCode() {
        return memberLanguageCode;
    }

    public void setMemberLanguageCode(String memberLanguageCode) {
        this.memberLanguageCode = memberLanguageCode;
    }
}
```

And my MemberRoles Entity class:

```
package com.ilkaygunel.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "MemberRoles.findByEmail", query = "select mr from MemberRoles mr where mr.email = :email") })
@Table(name = "MEMBERROLES")
public class MemberRoles {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "MEMBERROLES_ID")
    private long id;
    private String email;
    private String role;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MEMBERROLES_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Member member;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Member getMember() {
        return member;
    }

    public void setMember(Member member) {
        this.member = member;
    }
}
```

When I inserted a Member record, I check it on the database and see that Member and MemberRoles record have the same id. But why does MemberRoles area in response message has got id as 0?

My MemberSaveService class like this:

```
package com.ilkaygunel.service;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.ilkaygunel.constants.ConstantFields;
import com.ilkaygunel.entities.Member;
import com.ilkaygunel.entities.MemberRoles;
import com.ilkaygunel.exception.CustomException;
import com.ilkaygunel.exception.ErrorCodes;
import com.ilkaygunel.pojo.MemberOperationPojo;

@Service
public class MemberSaveService extends BaseService {

    public MemberOperationPojo addUserMember(List<Member> memberList) {
        return addBulkMember(memberList, ConstantFields.ROLE_USER.getConstantField());
    }

    public MemberOperationPojo addAdminMember(List<Member> memberList) {
        return addBulkMember(memberList, ConstantFields.ROLE_ADMIN.getConstantField());
    }

    public MemberOperationPojo addBulkMember(List<Member> memberList, String role) {
        Logger LOGGER = loggingUtil.getLoggerForMemberSaving(this.getClass());
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, resourceBundleMessageManager.getValueOfProperty(role + "_bulkMemberAddingMethod", "en"));
        MemberOperationPojo memberOperationPojo = new MemberOperationPojo();
        List<Member> savedMemberList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            memberUtil.checkEmailAddressAndLanguageOnMemberList(memberList, LOGGER);
            for (Member member : memberList) {
                addOneMember(member, role, LOGGER);
                savedMemberList.add(member);
            }
            memberOperationPojo.setResult(
                    resourceBundleMessageManager.getValueOfProperty(role + "_bulkMemberAddingSuccessfull", "en"));
            memberOperationPojo.setMemberList(memberUtil.removeFieldsFromReturningMember(savedMemberList));
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,
                    resourceBundleMessageManager.getValueOfProperty(role + "_bulkMemberAddingSuccessfull", "en")
                            + memberList);
        } catch (CustomException customException) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE,
                    resourceBundleMessageManager.getValueOfProperty(role + "_bulkMemberAddingFaled", "en")
                            + customException.getErrorCode() + " " + customException.getErrorMessage());
            memberOperationPojo.setErrorCode(customException.getErrorCode());
            memberOperationPojo.setResult(customException.getErrorMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE,
                    resourceBundleMessageManager.getValueOfProperty(role + "_bulkMemberAddingFaled", "en")
                            + e.getMessage());
            memberOperationPojo.setErrorCode(ErrorCodes.ERROR_10.getErrorCode());
            memberOperationPojo.setResult(e.getMessage());
        }
        return memberOperationPojo;
    }

    private void addOneMember(Member member, String role, Logger LOGGER) throws MessagingException {
        MemberOperationPojo memberOperationPojo = new MemberOperationPojo();
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, resourceBundleMessageManager.getValueOfProperty(role + "_memberAddingMethod",
                member.getMemberLanguageCode()));
        member.setPassword(getHashedPassword(member.getPassword()));
        member.setEnabled(false);
        addMemberRolesObject(role, member);
        addActivationToken(member);
        memberFacade.create(member);
        // mailUtil.sendActivationMail(member.getEmail(), member.getActivationToken());
        memberOperationPojo.setResult(resourceBundleMessageManager.getValueOfProperty(role + "_memberAddingSuccessfull",
                member.getMemberLanguageCode()));
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, resourceBundleMessageManager.getValueOfProperty(role + "_memberAddingSuccessfull",
                member.getMemberLanguageCode()) + member);
    }

    private String getHashedPassword(String rawPassword) {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(rawPassword);
    }

    private void addMemberRolesObject(String role, Member member) {
        MemberRoles rolesOfMember = new MemberRoles();
        rolesOfMember.setRole(role);
        rolesOfMember.setEmail(member.getEmail());
        rolesOfMember.setMember(member);
        member.setRoleOfMember(rolesOfMember);
    }

    private void addActivationToken(Member member) {
        String activationToken = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        member.setActivationToken(activationToken);

        LocalDateTime activationTokenExpDate = LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1);
        // LocalDateTime activationTokenExpDate = LocalDateTime.now();//Use for expire
        // date test!
        member.setActivationTokenExpDate(activationTokenExpDate);
    }
}
```

My Web Service End Point Class like this:

```
package com.ilkaygunel.restservice;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.ilkaygunel.entities.Member;
import com.ilkaygunel.pojo.MemberOperationPojo;
import com.ilkaygunel.service.MemberSaveService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/memberPostWebServiceEndPoint")
public class MemberSaveWebServiceEndPoint {
    @Autowired
    private MemberSaveService memberSaveService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveUserMember", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<MemberOperationPojo> saveUserMember(@RequestBody List<Member> memberList) {
        MemberOperationPojo memberOperationPojo = memberSaveService.addUserMember(memberList);
        return new ResponseEntity<MemberOperationPojo>(memberOperationPojo, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveAdminMember", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<MemberOperationPojo> saveAdminMember(@RequestBody List<Member> memberList) {
        MemberOperationPojo memberOperationPojo = memberSaveService.addAdminMember(memberList);
        return new ResponseEntity<MemberOperationPojo>(memberOperationPojo, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code inserting the member and returning a JSON response?

Comment: @JBNizet , I added MemberSaveService and MemberSaveWebServiceEndPoint codes. In MemberSaveWebServiceEndPoint I'm calling saveUserMember path and in MemberSaveService I'm calling addUserMember method.